# DatepickerDialog have conflict

Tags: android, kotlin

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI1T0.jpg)When I change the app language, datepicker have some conflicts[in this picture the picker is not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBL9V.jpg)

In some language the picker is work but another language it is not available.[In this picture the picker is work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKZ2i.jpg) I don't know how to find the mistakes

Comment: Your question is not fully understood. Don't forget to support it with code.